# Chamar uma pagina href passando os campos input do formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, jquery-mobile

Tenho uma pagina que tem diversos inputs, quando eu clico no botão eu abro um modal com o resultado e dentro dese modal tenho outro botão a ser clicado porém preciso pegar os campos do formulário e passar para a outra pagina.

Meu código do botão de detalhe está assim:

```
<div><center><a href="detalhado.html"  class='btn modal-action modal-close red'><strong><i class='mdi-content-add'></i> Detalhado</a></center></strong>
```

Aqui eu precisava passar os valores dos inputs exemplo:
**href="detalhado.html?valor=100000&meses=24&taxa=14.15"**

Comment: você já tentou utilizar jquery?, exemplo: var nome = $('#form01 #nome').val(); $('.modal #campoNome').val( nome );

Comment: Mas como faria isso passando no Href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) do jQuery para gerar a query string `valor=100000&meses=24&taxa=14.15` no click do botão:

```
$(function() { // Aguarda o DOM carregar
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Interrompe o browser de seguir para o href do botão

        var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Armazena o valor do atributo href do botão que foi clicado

        // Concatena os valores do form ao href e redireciona para a nova url
        window.location.href = href + '?' + $('form').serialize();
    });
});
```

https://jsbin.com/jaxabomedi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: criei uma pagina em branco para testar mas não funciona, sabe me dizer o pq? Testei no link que vc mandou e funciona perfeito.

Comment: @William atualizei a minha resposta. Adicionei o código dentro da função `$(function() {` para que o jQuery só execute o código quando o DOM estiver carregado

Comment: @@Marcos Lopes deu certo, obrigado!